# How can I use html audio tag with icon?

Tags: html, audio, mp4

I'm using an html audio control in a webpage to play an mp4 file.

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="example.m4a" type="audio/mp4">
</audio>
```

The tag displays a visual control specific to the platform.

[image]

How can I use the tag so that it displays a clickable icon of my choice instead of the default visual control?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe like this :

```js
    let a=0;document.getElementsByTagName("i")[0].addEventListener("click",function(){
if(a==0){
document.getElementsByTagName("audio")[0].play();a++;document.querySelector("i").style.opacity="1";
}else{
document.querySelector("audio").pause();a--;document.querySelector("i").style.opacity=".5";
}
});
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<div>
<h1 style="display:inline;color:grey;font-family:sans-serif;font-weight:normal;">Prison Walls</h1>
<span><i class="fa fa-volume-up fa-2x" style="color:grey;opacity:.5"></i></span>
</div>
<audio hidden>
  <source src="https://files.freemusicarchive.org/storage-freemusicarchive-org/music/ccCommunity/Julie_Maxwells_Piano_Music/Classic_Piano_Collection_from_the_Princess_of_Mars/Julie_Maxwells_Piano_Music_-_21_-_Prison_Walls.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
</body>
```

I used javascript `addEventListener` with traitement. So that, you can play or pause the audio. Also you can found the volume up icon you are looking for on https://fontawesome.com/icons/volume-up?style=solid.

Comment: Thanks Mohamed. For other noobs like me out there, I enclosed the first part of the answer "let a=0;document..." in <script> tags and copied it to bottom of my php file.

Comment: You wellcome Marc.